# Rails generate wrong method for "form_tag". How to fix that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

On on page, I have 2 forms like this:

```
<%= form_tag(create_car_service_settings_index_path, remote: true, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "service_type", 1 %>
  <%= text_field_tag "service_name", "", id: "service_name_car" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Service" %>
<% end %>

... some HTML ...

<%= form_tag(create_car_service_settings_index_path, remote: true, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "service_type", 0 %>
  <%= text_field_tag "service_name", "", id: "service_name_car" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Service" %>
<% end %>
```

The first form is rendered as `POST`, but the second one as `GET`; in `routes.rb` is following:

```
  resources :settings do
    collection do
      ...
      post 'create_car_service'
      post 'edit_car_service'
    end
  end
```

Why the second form is rendered as `GET` instead of `POST`? Stuck on this for a while.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

First form:

```
<form action="/settings/create_car_service" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

...

Second form:

```
<form action="/settings/create_car_service" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="get">
```

Comment: Why you have two forms for same action?

Comment: Because there are two types of services (`service_type ` -> 0/1).

Comment: what happens when you remove the `method: :post` from both forms?

Comment: Same output, no difference.

Comment: would it be convenient to post both your complete form view and probably your routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

When you do  bin/rails routes you should get something like this

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
create_car_service_settings POST   /settings/create_car_service(.:format) settings#create_car_service
edit_car_service_settings POST   /settings/edit_car_service(.:format)   settings#edit_car_service
```

So that post route should be create_car_service_settings_path not create_car_service_settings_index_path that points to settings#create_car_service

But it is a strange if you get for one method GET and other POST. Can you paste the output from these forms (html)

EDIT

So using the path that you provided generated an error for me. When I use this

```
 <%= form_tag(create_car_service_settings_path, remote: true, method: :post) do %>
```

I will get this for first

```
<form action="/settings/create_car_service" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

for second

```
<form action="/settings/create_car_service" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="service_type" id="service_type" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="service_name" id="service_name_car" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Service" data-disable-with="Add Service" />
</form>
```

Comment: Posted. Same Rails path helper, just once it generates `POST` (desired), secondly `GET`.

Comment: Did you try to change this line: <%= form_tag(create_car_service_settings_index_path, -> remove index as suggested above?

Comment: When I try your code  I get this: undefined local variable or method `create_car_service_settings_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc7c9a92098>:0x007fc7c9ab3248>
Did you mean?  create_car_service_settings_path
               create_car_service_settings_url...like I said I do not think that you can use create_car_service_settings_index_path since it should be create_car_service_settings_path...I am on rails 5